# Best practice for SQL join table

Tags: sql, join

Which is the best and fastest way to run a SQL query

Query #1:

```
Select A.column1, B.Column2, C.Column3 
From TableA A
Inner Join TableB B on B.id = A.id
Inner Join TableC C on C.id = A.id
Where a.ID = ....
```

or query #2:

```
Select A.id, A.column1, B.Column2, C.Column3 
From TableA A
Inner Join (Select id, column2 From TableB) B on B.id = A.id
Inner Join (Select id, Column3 From TableC) C on C.id = A.id
Where a.ID = ....
```

Comment: The second one will not work, as `B` has no `B.id`. And asking for "fastest" is not really on topic here: that is something you can benchmark yourself.

Comment: Most mature SQL products boil your query down to an internal query plan. Once you get the queries correct as per the prior comment, it's likely these two queries produce the same query plan and are no different. But it depends on a number of factors.

Comment: Go with alternative 1! Make it easy, and trust the optimizer!

Comment: @trincot,@nick Query corrected.. when the all three tables have many columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL engine does not run the actual SQL statement that you write.  It compiles the statement into a directed acyclic graph of operations (DAG) and then optimizes the graph.  What gets run looks nothing like the code you write.

In general, using subqueries around tables in the `FROM` clause does not help the optimizer, so in many databases it makes no difference.

However, some databases have this nasty habit of materializing subqueries.  In one of those databases, subqueries have a big impact on performance -- for the worse.  The data needs to be written and read (unnecessarily) and you may lose information such as indexes.

Experienced SQL users avoid unnecessary subqueries just because they are harder to interpret.  They add no additional information and lengthen the query.  I would recommend that you avoid them for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

First is a way to go. It is clearer and should be faster in most cases, as far as I know. I haven't seen second used. Also in such way second won't even work, you don't have keys in sub-queries.

You will need something like this:

```
Select A.column1,B.Column2,C.Column3 from TableA A
inner join (Select id, column2 from TableB) B on B.id=A.id
inner join (select id, Column3 from TableC) C on C.id=A.id
where a.ID=....
```